# What is the correct way to add/delete a DataRow to/from DataTable

Tags: datatable, datarow

I am facing problem adding and deleting DataRows from a DataTable that is meant for DataAdapter.Update(). I keep getting Concurrency error but I cannot figure where is wrong.

It happens when i add and delete rows from a DataTable.

At the moment, I add rows like this:

```
table.Rows.Add(new string{null /*pk*/, "composite_FK1", "composite_FK2", "composite_FK3"});
```

and i delete the last logical row in the DataTable like this:

```
DataRow[] rows = table.Select(string.Empty, string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

if (rows.Length > 0)
{
    DataRow row = rows[rows.Length - 1];
    if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
    {
        // directly remove this row because it is not in the database yet
        table.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
    else
    {
        // mark this row for deletion from the database
        row.Delete();
    }
}
```

After a few add and deletes, Update fails with Concurrency Exception. What can be a better way to add rows? Anyone can help spot the error please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to write your data to the database (inserts or updates), then read the data back from the database into your data table.

Answer (score 0):

For every adding and deleting u use table.acceptchanges(), hope it will work fine

Comment: @kaylyan are you saying after every update? before AcceptChanges removes all the RowState information... am i not right?

Comment: If, u r deleting a row in the datatable, and still if u want to delete some more rows, after deleting all them atlast right this acceptchanges() property, same for Update.